# Condition for an expression to be a total differential

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential

I have fully understood the concept and formulae around total differentials of multivariate functions.
What is the condition however for an expression of differentials to be the total differential of a function?
More specifically, what is the condition so that
$
\Phi(dx, dy, dz) = df 
$ where $\Phi$ is an expression and $f:\mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms

Comment: @Chappers - Thanks, I didn't know that's what they're called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an "expression" (really, a [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form)) $\Phi(dx,dy,dz)$ is said to be **exact** if there exists some $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $\Phi = df$. This is what you're looking for.

A necessary condition for a form to be exact is that it has to be **closed**, i.e. $d\Phi = 0$ itself. This is because $d(df)$ is always zero, a result following from the [symmetry of partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) (a good exercise). As it turns out, by the [Poincaré lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar.C3.A9_lemma), this is also sufficient: as soon as $d\Phi = 0$, there exists $f$ such that $\Phi = df$. This is something very special about $\mathbb{R}^n$, or more generally contractible open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For more complicated manifolds (or, if you haven't learned about manifolds yet, you can think about open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$), this is no longer true. An exact form (i.e. a form $\Phi$ of the type $df$) is necessary closed (i.e. $d\Phi = 0$), but the converse is not necessarily true: there may be closed 1-forms that aren't exact. An example is given by the form $(-ydx+xdy)/(x^2+y^2)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$). This is encoded by [de Rham cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology).